# Ruby on rails to_param with multiple fields for SEO

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest, seo

I am trying to make my urls prettier and still use restful resources. I understand that you can override the to_param method if you object has a **name** property like this:

```
def to_param
  self.name
end
```

which will give you the route **/:model/:name**. This is all straightforward, but I have to be capable of having the same name with multiple different languages. I haven't been able to find a blog entry on how to do this, so how can i override the to_param method to provide me a route similar to **/:model/:language/:name**  ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could always do:

```
/language/:language/model/:name
```

You'd do this with nested routes:

```
map.resources :languages do |l|
  l.resources :profiles
end
```

Then your route would be:

```
langauge_profile_url('spanish', @profile)
```

However...

Depending on what you're trying to do you might be better of using the built in [rails i18n](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html) stuff.  Is this so users can browse the site in different languages??

Comment: ok, how do I do this?

The my model is "person", so a person named "bob" who speaks "spanish" would need to be represented as /language/spanish/person/bob according to this answer. Seems reasonable, can you point me to a resource on how to do this?

Comment: do you know how to set up routes to do something like that?

Comment: i actually already using i18n though i have duplicate name pairs in my database (with a different language field) I was hoping that I could get away without having to specify anything special and have my old routes "just work" in the grand scheme of things i guess it doesn't take that much extra time.

Comment: You could always specify the language and store it in a cookie?  That way you don't have to show it in the route.